# How to set up multiple separate git repo in one Ubuntu?

Tags: git, ubuntu

I already create a git repo for the dev team, and save dev team members' pub keys in `/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys`, so that the dev team can do `git clone ssh://git@22.29.11.1:8066/projects/dev.git` and push code.

Now I want to set another git repo for the test team in the same Ubuntu, something like `git@22.29.11.1:8066/projects/testing.git`, and **the two teams should not access each other's git repo**, but looks now I only have one `/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys` to save pub keys...

Can someone please share the solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using an establish Git repo server solution.

If cloud is not available for some reason, then I would install a self-hosted  version of one of the cloud providers. Just type in `git self-hosted` in you favourite search engine.

Security is hard to get right.